# Dialog does not close on web version of Outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in that opens a dialog box using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` with `displayInIframe: true`

When I click the 'X' close button in the top righthand corner nothing happens.

[image: dialog with 'X' close button highlighted]

Similarly, when I call `dialog.close()` or `Office.context.ui.closeContainer()` nothing happens.

I have tested this on chrome and edge, both have this issue (I have not tested other browsers).

On the desktop app this works without any issues.

Simplified code for displaying the dialog window:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 60, width: 60, displayInIframe: true }, asyncResult => {
        if (handleError(asyncResult)) return;

        dialog = asyncResult.value;

        const dialogClosed = async (_: any): Promise<void> => {
            console.log("dialogClosed");
        };

        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, dialogClosed);
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);

        const promises = [];

        {working business logic}

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
            {working business logic}

            event.completed();
        });
    });
```

If I add an event handler for DialogEventRecieved, as far as I can tell this is never triggered on web.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your code for displying a dialog window?

Comment: I have added the code snippet to the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be related to the following part of your code:

```
const promises = [];

        {working business logic}

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
            {working business logic}

            event.completed();
        });
```

Try to remove any extra code for promises and just use something like that:

```
let dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html',
    function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
    }
);

function processMessage(arg) {
    dialog.close();

  // message processing code goes here;

}
```

Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

Comment: I replaced my dialog code with your example and it does work. Although, further investigation shows that it's not the promises causing the issue.

If I remove the `event.completed()` line it works (even with the promises). I take it I should be subscribing to `DialogEventReceived` so that I can call `event.completed()` once the dialog has been closed?

Comment: Yes,, there is no need to call the `event.completed()` in the callback.